# how to do forms in html?

Tags: html

How do I do a browse button, that when clicked on will just open the browse box, and store the  link to the file in its value, I don't want it to connect to any server or anything (so i'm not sure what to do for the action and method attributes...). Basically after the user browses for a file, they can click another button and an onclick event occurs, but when I try it, it's not functioning properly.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input name="fileupload" id="fileupload" type="file">
    <input value="OK" type="submit" onclick="change_bg_img('Untitled.png');">
</form>
```

Comment: what is not functioning exactly?

Comment: its supposed to change the bg image of a canvas in html5, but after i click the button, nothing happens, and the input box becomes blank.

Comment: if I try this
      <form action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.cgi" method="POST">
       Image URL:
       <input type="text" id="_bg_type_" size="30" value=""/>
       <input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="change_bg_img(_bg_type_.value);"/>
      </form>

then it works

Comment: show us `change_bg_img` code then

Comment: i dont think this will help, but here:

function change_bg_img(val) {
 if (using_logo() && val!="") {
  alert("Can't use background image when using a logo."); 
  return -1;
 }
 document.getElementById('bg_img').innerHTML = val;
 drawCanvas();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an input of `type="submit"`. Clicking it will submit the form, so the JavaScript will run, then the page will reload in its default state.

If you don't want to ever submit the data to the server then:

- Don't use a `<form>`
- Use `type="button"` not `type="submit"`

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, you don't actually need a form here.

I've made a working example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/h774q/2/

Use a button.  And for best practices keep your click event handler out of the markup ;)